# SQL Server 2008 FILESTREAM Progress Indicator

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1, filestream

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with a table that contains a FILESTREAM varbinary(max) column.  I have set up the database server to use file streaming and everything works well.  I have also created a client application using C# + Entity Framework 4.1 (Visual Studio 2010)—this too works well and I can read and write to the varbinary(max) column without any difficulty.  My problem is this: for very large files it can take a while to upload/download the file data from the database.  Is there a way that I can determine how much progress has been made and notify the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No because EF doesn't support `filestream`. Once you mapped it as `varbinary(max)` it is accessed in exactly same way as any other `varbinary` column and must be completely fetched. If you want to take advantage of advanced `filestream` features you must use native SQL through ADO.NET.